# .htaccessファイルを書き換えて、http→httpsへリダイレクトしないようにしたい

Tags: .htaccess

httpsのURLのwordpressサイトの移転作業をしています。
移転先サーバーへ、wordpressとDBのデータをアップロードして、ネームサーバー切り替えの前に、表示動作確認をしたいのですが、移転先サーバーのアドレスを入力しても、httpsのアドレスへリダイレクトされて、確認できません。

こちらのサイト等を参考にして、ファイルの内容の一部をコメントアウトしていますが、リダイレクトされてしまいます。
[.htaccessによるリダイレクト操作の書き方まとめ。SSL化や別ドメインへの301リダイレクト、 wwwありなしの統一方法など](https://wemo.tech/1886)

どの部分をコメントアウトや、書き換えれば良いのかご教授いただきないでしょうか？

◆コメントアウトした箇所

```
# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[3.2.9]
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
#</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
# BEGIN WordPress
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
#</IfModule>
```

◆.htaccessファイル全てのコード

```
# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[3.2.9]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN ブラウザキャッシュ

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      <ifModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive On

        # キャッシュ初期化
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

        # CSS
        ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

        # RSS
        ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
        ExpiresByType application/rdf+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
        ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

        # データはキャッシュさせない
        ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
        ExpiresByType application/ld+json                   "access plus 0 seconds"
        ExpiresByType application/schema+json               "access plus 0 seconds"
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.geo+json              "access plus 0 seconds"
        ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
        ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"

        # Favicon
        ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon              "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

        # HTML
        ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"

        # JavaScript
        ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType text/js                               "access plus 1 month"

        # マニフェスト
        ExpiresByType application/manifest+json             "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
        ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"

        # 画像や動画
        ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/bmp                             "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/jpg                             "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/webp                            "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"

        # Webフォント
        # Embedded OpenType (EOT)
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType font/eot                              "access plus 1 month"

        # OpenType
        ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"

        # TrueType
        ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"

        # Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 1.0
        ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff               "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType font/woff                             "access plus 1 month"

        # Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 2.0
        ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 month"

        # Other
        ExpiresByType text/x-cross-domain-policy            "access plus 1 week"

      </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    # END ブラウザキャッシュ

    # BEGIN Gzip圧縮
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
      SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

      # Mozilla4系などの古いブラウザで無効、しかしMSIEは除外
      BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
      BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
      BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

      # gifやjpg、pngなど圧縮済みのコンテンツは再圧縮しない
      SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$ no-gzip dont-vary
      SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI _\.utxt$ no-gzip
      #DeflateCompressionLevel 4

      # 有効な圧縮
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom_xml
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
    </IfModule>
    # END Gzip圧縮
    # END WordPress
```

［追記］Apacheアクセスログ

```
[13/Mar/2020:10:11:43 +0900] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
```

［追記2］移転先サーバーへデータをアップロードした後の、動作の確認方法

以下のサイトを参考に確認しています（私の場合はMacなので/etc/hosts/のファイルにコードを加えています）
[サイト引越しの際、ネームサーバー変更前に”特定”のPCでのみ移転後の表示確認を行う方法](https://site-hikkoshi.com/1803/)

Comment: まず `.htaccess` を置かない状態での動作はどうなるか確認してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。.htaccessのファイルを削除して試してみましたが、httpsへリダイレクトされてしまいます。

Comment: 現象としてはhtaccessではないところでリダイレクトされているといことなのでそれを絞り込むことが大事かと思います。Apacheのアクセスログではどのような転送ログが残っていますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。リダイレクトしないように設定し、アクセスした際のログは以下の通りになっております。（移転先サーバーのIPアドレスは、XXX.XX.XXX.XXXに変えてあります）

Comment: heck.aspx HTTP/1.1" 404 214 "http://api.gxout.com/proxy/check.aspx" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
220.194.91.101 - - [12/Mar/2020:17:10:56 +0900] "GET

Comment: http://jophiel.map.qq.com/proxy/?proxy=160.16.117.138:80&uuid=default HTTP/1.1" 404 204 "-" "silverfox"
51.15.71.134 - - [12/Mar/2020:17:11:33 +0900] "GET http://stat.labs.altnet.biz:80/service/gate.php?getdata=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80 HTTP/1.1" 404 214 "-" "HellEngine/2.0 (Linux) HellChecker/2.0"
14.248.111.48 - - [12/Mar/2020:17:11:34 +0900] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"

Comment: 申し訳ないです、コメントに記述するのではなくて質問に追記する形でお願いします。

Comment: 失礼しました。質問にアクセスログの内容を記載しました。サーバーにアクセスし、その時間帯のアクセスのログを記載しています。こちらのものが対象のログになりますでしょうか？

Comment: あとは、httpd.confに転送の処理が書いていないか？ロードバランサー側でSSLにしていないかかなあ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpressの一般設定で「WordPress アドレス (URL)」にhttpsでアドレスを指定していると、そちらへリダイレクトされるかと思います。
下記のコードを「wp-config.php」に記述することで、URLを一時的に変更できるようです。
なお、必要なくなったら、該当コードをコメントアウトするか、削除してください。

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com'); // WordPress アドレス (URL)
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com'); // サイトアドレス (URL)
```

また、もう1つ確認する点として、同じく「wp-config.php」に下記のようなコードが挿入されている可能性があります。

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] === "https") {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
    define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
    define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
}
```

このようなコードが存在する場合、1度コメントアウトしてどうなるかお試しください。
以上、参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。「WordPress アドレス (URL)」にhttpsでアドレスを指定していましたので、「wp-config.php」にご指定のコードを記述したのですが、解決できませんでした。なお、if(iseet(~~~のコードはありませんでした。

Comment: １つ気になったのですが、質問文中の「移転先サーバのアドレス」とは、何を示しているのでしょうか。Wordpressを独自ドメインで運用している場合、ネームサーバーを変更するなどで移転先サーバに向ける必要があると思うのですが。

Comment: 現在運用中のURLをhttps→httpにしたものです。こちらの記事の方法を参考に移転先サーバーの動作を確認しています。https://site-hikkoshi.com/1803/。私の場合はマックを使用していますので、Mac OS X /etc/hosts/を、ドメイン「sitemart.jp」の場合 ○○○.○○○.○○○.○○○ sitemart.jpというようにして、確認しています。ブラウザでhttp://sitemart.jpとURLを入力しても、表示されずURLはhttpからhttpsの表示となってしまいます。chromeを使用していますが、This site can’t be reachedxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx refused to connect.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSEDの表示となります。

Comment: .htaccessの内容を見て思い当たったのですが、「ReallySimpleSSL」というプラグインを利用していますか？もし利用している場合、一度プラグインを無効化する必要がありそうです。詳しくは、下記のサイトあたりが参考になると思います。 [WordPressのプラグインReallySimpleSSLを手動で解除する方法](https://its-office.jp/blog/wordpress/2017/09/23/non-ssl-form-ssl.html)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ReallySimpleSSLのプラグイン利用していますので、紹介していただいたサイトを参考に試してみたいと思います。少々時間がかかりそうなので、追って結果をお知らせします。取り急ぎ情報いただいたお礼までです。

Comment: https://its-office.jp/blog/wordpress/2017/09/23/non-ssl-form-ssl.htmlこちらのサイトの方法を行う事で、httpsのアドレスへリダイレクトしないようになりました。そして移転先サーバーで動作確認する事ができました。ご協力ありがとうございました！